# Allocate column values based on distribution

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table `revenue` with a column `net_revenue`:

```
net_revenue
------------
100
200
```

That I need to allocate based on the following distribution:

```
A: 5%
B: 10%
C: 25%
D: 60%
```

And end up with:

```
| net_revenue | product |
|-------------|---------|
| 5           | A       |
| 10          | B       |
| 25          | C       |
| 60          | D       |
| 10          | A       |
| 20          | B       |
| 50          | C       |
| 120         | D       |
```

I have been able to successfully do this with some case statements and joins but it has gotten messy rather quickly and I was hoping to learn a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be

```
SELECT net_revenue * 0.05 AS net_revenue, 'A' AS product
UNION ALL
SELECT net_revenue * 0.10 AS net_revenue, 'B' AS product
UNION ALL
SELECT net_revenue * 0.25 AS net_revenue, 'C' AS product
UNION ALL
SELECT net_revenue * 0.60 AS net_revenue, 'D' AS product;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a simple cross join with some mathematics, if you have stored your percentage in another table -

```
SELECT (r.net_revenue * p.percent)/100, p.product
FROM products p, revenue r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross join along with a hard-coded values table. Assuming your table with the `net_revenue` column is called `rev_table`:

```
SELECT
  rev_table.net_revenue * p.pct as net_revenue,
  p.product
FROM
  rev_table,
  (VALUES ('A', 0.05), ('B', 0.1), ('C', 0.25), ('D', 0.6)) as p (product, pct)
```